# How do I pass the grid of stones to the diamond?

Tags: payday-2

There's a grid of stones on the way to the diamond in the diamond exhibition room in the newest heist, The Diamond.

Kind of like Indiana Jones, where one must carefully step on the right steps to avoid traps, we attempted to make our ways across, only to hit the wrong one and trigger the alarms.

What is the correct path across each time? Is it randomnated, are there clues around the map that will tell us which stone to step on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a circuit box on the left when you enter the chamber that you need to activate. Every time you activate, some of the red lights will turn green forming a path from the bottom to the top. Each of the lights corresponds to a tile on the floor, the bottom row being the closest to you. You must follow the path indicated by the green lights. The path will only last 30 seconds though, so if you're alone, you must be quick. The path changes each time you use it.

[image: example of the server lights]

Comment: Is it the same each time or is it completely changed in different heists?

Comment: @memescientist It changes, edited.

Comment: While not mentioned, the 30 seconds is only applicable on Death Wish difficulty. On Overkill, it is 60 seconds, and on Very Hard and below, there is no timer and the pattern does not reset.